# Autocomplete for CVC remembers past values on Firefox

Tags: html, autocomplete, payment, autofill

I added some autocomplete attributes on my payment form to allow Chrome and Safari users to save their credit card in their browsers.

I followed the Google [Autofill](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill?hl=en) instructions to do so.

```
<label for="frmNameCC">Name on card</label>
<input name="ccname" id="frmNameCC" required placeholder="Full Name" autocomplete="cc-name">

<label for="frmCCNum">Card Number</label>
<input name="cardnumber" id="frmCCNum" required autocomplete="cc-number">

<label for="frmCCCVC">CVC</label>
<input name="cvc" id="frmCCCVC" required autocomplete="cc-csc">

<label for="frmCCExp">Expiry</label>
<input name="cc-exp" id="frmCCExp" required placeholder="MM-YYYY" autocomplete="cc-exp">
```

*By the way the official specs only use on or off as a value for the autocomplete attribute...*

Anyways, it works pretty well. Unfortunately on Firefox (which doesn't have the feature to save a credit card) the input for CVC number [autocomplete="cc-csc"] remembers past values and suggests them in a dropdown list, which is really bad for security. At least, it seems to not remember past values of the card number input [autocomplete="cc-number"] which is the most important one.

Any workaround to suggest other than setting the CVC autocomplete to off.
If you have any documentation about FF behavior/support of those autocomplete values I'd really appreciate!

PS: I haven't checked on Internet Explorer/Edge.